# Shop products not aligning due to product title

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Should be an easy question for you all.

Our WooCommerce products won't align due to the length of the product's title. I'm looking to fix this with more of a consistant 'grid'. Can you all help? I know it has to do with some CSS, but I can't figure out what to do. Any help will be much appreciated.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRWA5.jpg)

I've tried some CSS Snippets, but to no avail.

[Shop Page to see](https://www.fralinpickups.com/shop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add fixed height to `.woocommerce .products h2, .woocommerce .cross-sells h2`
you can change the `justify-content` to position your text

```
.woocommerce .products h2, .woocommerce .cross-sells h2 {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 3%;
    margin: 0 3% 0.2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    height: 65px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this creates some pretty large gaps between the product title and rating. I wonder if we can do the same concept, but underneath the star rating?

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks @RamSegev!